# Do I use Java lambda appropriately for this strategy pattern?

Tags: java, lambda

I use lambda expression + Function to implement a strategy pattern, do I use it correctly and appropriately ?

```
public void deploy(WatcherConfig config) {
    performOnWatch(config, a -> {
        deployWatch(a);
        return null;
    });
}

public void delete(final WatcherConfig config) {
    performOnWatch(config, a -> {
        deleteWatch(a);
        return null;
    });
}

public void performOnWatch(WatcherConfig config, Function<WatchConfig, Void> function) {
    for (WatchConfig watchConfig : config.getWatchConfigs()) {
        List<WatchConfig> realConfigs = WatchUtils.parseWatchParameter(watchConfig);
        for(WatchConfig realWatchConfig : realConfigs) {
            function.apply(realWatchConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, does it work? If so, sure. If not, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simplify the `performOnWatch` method using streams if you implement a `streamWatchConfigs` to replace `getWatchConfigs` (which presumably returns a collection):

```
public void performOnWatch(WatcherConfig config, Consumer<WatchConfig> consumer) {
    config.streamWatchConfigs()
        .flatMap(WatchUtils::parseWatchParameters)
        .forEach(consumer::accept);
}

performOnWatch(config, this::deployWatch);
performOnWatch(config, this::deleteWatch);
```

Comment: whether to use stream is a matter of personal preference, but Consumer is definitely better than function here.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you are using the word "pattern" you are digging yourself into a terrible mental hole.  That's why I wish that pattern book was never written.  Stop thinking about patterns.  Forget their names.  Think in terms of what you need to get done and what tools the language gives you to solve the problem in a way that combines flexibility, readability of the code and performance.  Patterns are mental crutches.  If you are smart enough to use patterns correctly, you don't need patterns.  IF you are not, patterns will hurt you more than help you.

Comment: That's interesting. Could you recommend some further reading?

Comment: For me it just smells of attempt to sell common sense and I am allergic to that.  See this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990899/design-patterns-criticism-sources

Answer (score 1):

Seems legit. The only thing I would change is using `Consumer<WatchConfig>` instead of `Function<WatchConfig, Void>`. It will simplify method signatures as well as strategy implementations (there will be no need to `return null` from strategy).

Also if `deleteWatch()` and `deployWatch()` returns null and if you will use `Consumer` code can be rewritten as:

```
performOnWatch(config, this::deployWatch);

performOnWatch(config, this::deleteWatch);
```